# Insert HTML codes to specific location

Tags: php, html, insert

I know this topic was posted everywhere, but their question is not I want. I want to insert some HTML codes before the page is loaded **without touching the original code in the page.**

Suppose my header was rendered by a function called render_header():

```
function render_body() {
return "<body>
    <div class='container'>
    <div class='a'>A</div>
    <div class='b'>B</div>
    </div>
    </body>";
}
```

From now, I want to insert HTML codes using PHP **without editing the render_body()**. I want a function that **insert some divs to container'div**.

```
render_body();
<?php *//Insert '<div class="c" inside div container* ?>
```

Comment: so why dont you create some page with those codes that you want and `include_once`?

Comment: Your function will fail because you're not escaping the double quotes.

Comment: Assuming that `render_body()` is a globally included function used all over the shop (and you've fixed the syntax with the quotes), you could use DOMDocument I suppose to read in `render_body()` as a string and manipulate it after the fact : http://uk3.php.net/domdocument

Comment: For further reference its bad to use `'` as the HTML tag you should do the opposite, keep it with `"` and make the return with `'`.

Comment: @Prix, I don't see any double quotes that need escaping...

Comment: @Prix, My bad - OP changed the post... gah..

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is to turn on output buffering and then use the `DOMDocument` class to read in the entire buffer and then make changes to it. It is worth doing some reading of the documentation (http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) provided in the script...

ie.:

```
<?php


function render_body() {
return "<body>
    <div class='container'>
    <div class='a'>A</div>
    <div class='b'>B</div>
    </div>
    </body>";
}  

$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML(render_body());

// get body tag
$body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);

// add a new element at the end of the body
$element = $dom->createElement('div', 'My new element at the end!');
$body->appendChild($element);

echo $dom->saveHTML(); // echo what is in the dom

?>
```

EDIT:

As per CD001's suggestions, I have tested this code and it works.

Comment: Do you really need to turn on output buffering? The function `render_body()` isn't actually rendering the body (weirdly) it's just returning a string containing it - you could just use `$dom->loadHTML(render_body());`

Comment: ... bit of a "circlejerk" - but this answer is equally valid and was up before mine so +1 ;)

Comment: Cheers man, but as I said in the comment on yours..if the OP understands XPath, that is the best option as it will be much faster for PHP to parse.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternative using XPath - this should load in the output from `render_body()` to an XML ([DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)) object and create an [XPath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) object to query your HTML so you can easily work out where you want to insert the new HTML.

This will probably only work if you're using XML well formed HTML though.

```
//read in the document
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadHTML(render_body());

//create an XPath query object
$xpath = new DOMXpath($xml);

//create the HTML nodes you want to insert
// using $xml->createElement() ...

//find the node to which you want to attach the new content
$xmlDivClassA = $xpath->query('//body/div[@class="a"]')->item(0);
$xmlDivClassA->appendChild( /* the HTML nodes you've previously created */ );

//output
echo $xml->saveHTML();
```

Took a little while as I had to refer to the documentation ... too much JQuery lately it's ruining my ability to manipulate the DOM without looking things up :\

Comment: This is quite nice if you know xpath. Would be super fast too +1.